# How to Configure the Tomcat7 production server?

Tags: java, tomcat, tomcat7

Am new to tomcat server. I need to configure the server.

**Specification:**

**OS**     : Linux unknown, amd64/64 (8 cores)

**RAM**    : 4GB

**Server** : Tomcat7

**JAVA**   : OpenJDK Runtime Environment, 1.6.0_24-b24

**JVM**    : OpenJDK 64-Bit Server VM, 20.0-b12, mixed mode

What are all the option i need give in **setenv.sh** file. Currently i give the option like below,

```
export CATALINA_OPTS="-Xms512M -Xmx1024M -XX:PermSize=64M
                      -XX:MaxPermSize=512M -XX:MaxNewSize=1024m
                      -XX:NewSize=1024m -XX:+UseParNewGC
                      -XX:TargetSurvivorRatio=90 -XX:+CMSClassUnloadingEnabled 
                      -XX:+CMSPermGenSweepingEnabled -XX:+UseConcMarkSweepGC
                      -XX:+CMSParallelRemarkEnabled -XX:+UseCMSInitiatingOccupancyOnly
                      -XX:CMSInitiatingOccupancyFraction=70
                      -XX:+ScavengeBeforeFullGC
                      -XX:+CMSScavengeBeforeRemark
                      -Dcom.sun.management.jmxremote.port=8999
                      -Dcom.sun.management.jmxremote.authenticate=false
                      -Dcom.sun.management.jmxremote.ssl=false"
```

These option are enough or i need modify or add any option. Till now am using default option(in default option server getting down after one day). please help me to configure production server.

Comment: Did you obtain an error after down?? I think it is very strange, that with default options server goes down each days...

Comment: @Teo one time i got **OutOfMemory** error. With this default option when i start the Tomcat in morning means tomcat slow down and Server down on next day evening.

Comment: I'm not sure 64bit & 4GB physical RAM. Has this machine additional functions? SQL, cache etc?

Answer (score 0):

If you are sure your web-app didn't generate that error, you could try to read this: [Tomcat Wiki](http://wiki.apache.org/tomcat/OutOfMemory) and then you can increase the `PermGen`